# Something wrong with the ad system today?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, advertising

This could just be me misunderstanding the way marketing works, but I have seen a few adds today that just look weird. One of them was just title text and no background or border etc. Another example is included below.

I am using Firefox 15.0.1 on Windows.

Is this an issue or just me?

> [image]

**UPDATE:** Just looking at Firebug and I spotted this.

For #launched-ad in the style tab

```
background: url("/content/Img/launched-ads/security.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
```

I am getting the message

> Failed to load the given URL

**UPDATE 2:** The other ad that I came across earlier appears to have the same problem with this background image

```
url("/content/Img/launched-ads/photo.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent
```

Comment: I have still got the tab open with the screen above if there is any info that is needed to help with debugging. Will close it in 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a temporary issue when our CDN went down.  Everything should be working now.